# "Home" in a non-literal sense

Tags: traducción, español-neutral

I know *home* translates as **casa** or, in some contexts, **hogar**. But both these terms refer to a more literal idea than I'd like to use at times. They both seem to refer to the actual house.

Let's imagine I am on a grueling expedition in the middle of the Amazon rainforest and getting weary and edgy by the day. At some point, my tolerance gives in and I tell my friends in frustration, "When will all this be over? I just wanna go home!" Here, I am merely expressing my desire to return to my comfort zone more than the actual physical house that I live in. How do I express this in Spanish?

Comment: Excellent job on providing specific context for your question!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We actually use `casa` to say something like what has been given in the example

> Quiero volver a casa!
>
> Con lo bien que estaba yo en mi casa y me he tenido que venir al Amazonas!

`Casa` is a pretty generic word in Spanish, and we used to refer not only to a house, but to where we live (no matter if house, apartment, etc.)

> Qué bien se está en casa calentito cuando nieva fuera
>
> Vives todavía en casa de tus padres?

In Spain you would barely hear `Hogar` to refer to the place that gives you shelter. Maybe in songs or literature, because the word has become old fashioned to refer to a house or building. Nevertheless `Hogar` has a boarder meaning, and can refer to the place where an individual or groups inhabits.

> El Amazonas es el **hogar** de muchas especies de animales
>
> Llevamos al gato callejero que encontramos a un hogar para animales  <sub>We took the stray cat we found to a shelter for animals</sub>

You wouldn't be saying "quiero regresar al hogar" unless you where trying to sound poetic or where referring to an an abstract place.

Comment: I should have been clearer when I said non-literal. I know the difference in nuances between house, apartment, condo, villa, etc. and that's not what I was referring to. Let me illustrate with another example: "Palestine is my home and I'll die in it." Would you still use casa in this context?

Comment: Since you are referring to a country, you could use "patria" (Palestina es mi patria) but with that connotation, you would have to use "home" indeed (Palestina es mi hogar y moriré en ella). I'll update the answer.

Comment: There are some places in Spain where the word *hogar* is in wider use. I have a friend from Asturias who always says *mi hogar* for what I would say *mi casa*.

Answer (score 1):

### Hogar is the Habitat

If you say, `mi hogar` you're pretty much saying something like

> My dwelling

If you want to translate things verbatim, then using hogar would be the appropriate word for literal translation.  Literal translation as in:

`Me gusta la flor` - **VS** -  `Me it pleases the flower`

### Mi casa es su casa

The culture attached to the Spanish language has emulsified the word `hogar` into `casa`