# Difference between casa and hogar

Tags: selección-de-palabras, uso-de-palabras

What is the difference between casa and hogar. They both mean home, don't they?

Comment: [Here](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/10696/5481) there is a really similar question. Although technically not a duplicate, I think [the answers](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/10698/5481) to this question may answer yours.

Comment: Still doesn't help.

Comment: Could you be more specific? The difference is the same as between "house" and "home", plus you have all the extra information of the linked question. Maybe you should clarify what is giving you trouble.

Comment: Please consult a dictionary for both words, and if you still have a doubt, explain that doubt in your question, and flag for moderator attention to re-open.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is answerable by a dictionary or other reference material.

Comment: Well, if you look them up in RAE, you'll see that *hogar* means "casa" or "familia que vive junta" plus other unrelated meanings. And casa also means "familia", so I think the dictionary (at least this one) does not really answer the question.

Comment: @MikMik: Then the OP can easily elaborate on their confusion and have the question re-opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  "Casa" is a house.  "Hogar" is a home.   The former is more generic, while the latter assumes more of a personal connection/affinity for the place one lives in.

Comment: Gracias mucho!!

Comment: How about "sentirse como en casa"? It does not refer to "a house", but rather to "home".

Comment: @MikMik: "en casa" implies "en tu casa", which can also be interpreted as your home.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, that "casa" can have the "home" meaning too.

Comment: @MikMik: No todas las casas son hogares, ni todos los hogares son casas.